# Преобразовать строку в Json

Tags: php, json, curl

Как преобразовать `JSON` строку в массив по [этому запросу](http://tajmarket.ru/tetes/files/)?

Код:

```
$cookies=tmpfile();
$ch = curl_init("https://s.taobao.com/search?ajax=true&callback=&app=imgsearch&tfsid=TB1jNPyLFXXXXXxXFXXXXXXXXXX");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'IE20');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookies);//используем куки
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookies);
$page=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$json = json_decode($page,true);
var_dump($json);
```

Comment: по этой ссылке лежат данные в формате json. Можете задать вопрос в более развёрнутой форме?

Comment: `var_dump($page)` покажи

Comment: @zenith тогда как вызвать массив например "title" ?

Comment: @zenith это не валидный JSON

Answer (score 1):

Прежде всего, ошибка состоит в том, что сервер возвращает неправитьные JSON данные в формате

```
{
    "pageName":"imgsearch",
    "mods":{ ... },
    ...
    "map": {}
}
int(1) Скрипт выполнялся 3.6537 сек.
```

Строка "int(1) Скрипт выполнялся 3.6537 сек." является источноком проблемы. Кстати, я бы проекомендовал http://jsonlint.com/ для проверки JSON данных.

Во-вторых, терминология "преобразовать строку в Json" - неверная. JSON - это очень простой формат передачи *объекта в виде строки*, очень похожей на инициализацию объекта. Например, следующий фрагмент JavaScript кода

```
var myObject = {
        x: 1,
        closed: true,
        name: "Олег",
        "my comment": "Он сказал: \"Поехали!\""
    };
```

создает и инициализирует объект. Соответствующий объект в JSON формате выглядит так:

```
{
    "x": 1,
    "closed": true,
    "name": "Олег",
    "my comment": "Он сказал: \"Поехали!\""
}
```

Он очень похож на инициализацию объекта, но это - разные вещи. **JSON - это уже строка**. Поэтому код, приведенный выше можно переписать так:

```
var str = '{"x":1,"closed":true,"name":"Олег","my comment":"Он сказал: \"Поехали!\""}';
var myObject = JSON.parse(str);
```

Я хочу подчеркнуть, что JSON - это всегда строка в которой закодирорана информация об объекте. Поэтому фраза "преобразовать строку в Json", в вашем случае, не имеет смысла. Вы подразумевали преобразование строки, с информацией в JSON формате, к объекту. Я рекомендую Вам взглянуть на http://json.org/, где описан JSON формат. Он очень прост и описывается всего лишь парой диаграмм.

Comment: Спасибо за ответь, но вопрос все еще актуален, вот теперь код поменял:    `$cookies=tmpfile();
    $ch = curl_init("https://s.taobao.com/search?    ajax=true&callback=&app=imgsearch&tfsid=TB1jNPyLFXXXXXxXFXXXXXXXXXX");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'IE20');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookies);//используем куки
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookies);
$page=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$json = substr($page,-1);
$json = json_decode($page,true);
print_r($json);` но почему то все еще не валидный.

Comment: @mega94:  Вопрос был: "Как преобразовать JSON строку в массив по [этому запросу](http://tajmarket.ru/tetes/files/)?" Ответ от http://tajmarket.ru/tetes/files/ изменился, но все еще непавильный. Он заканчивается `,"... map":{}}1` с ненужной `1`, которая делает формат инвалидным.

Comment: это да, но я питаюсь избавиться от этого сделав `substr($page, 0, -1);` но почему то это не помогает. А как тогда избавиться и получит   формат json?

Comment: @mega94: Я, вообще, не использию PHP, но причина Вашей проблемы, как я понимаю, - это инвалидный ответ от http://tajmarket.ru/tetes/files/ который содержит ненужный символ. Вам нүжно правльно возвращать JSON данные без wrapping.